# What are the problems with my List<T> implementation? 

Tags: c++, list

I created a small implementation of the container list that performs certain functions based on a test `main()` I was given.

I wanted to add some extra functions to it. Mainly an `operator[]`, and a `reverse()` function that displays the numbers in the list backwards.

Here is my code, everything with a comment was added to it yesterday.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template <class T> class Link;
template <class T> class List_iterator;
template <class T> class Reverse_iterator;

template <class T> 
class List
{
public:
   typedef List_iterator<T> iterator;

   List();
   List(const List<T> & l);
   ~List();

   bool empty() const;
   unsigned int size() const; 
   T & back() const;
   T & front() const;
   void push_front(const T & x);
   void push_back(const T & x);
   void pop_front();
   void pop_back();
   iterator begin() const;
   iterator end() const;
   iterator rbegin() const;//REVERSE BEGIN
   iterator rend() const; //REVERSE END
   void insert(iterator pos, const T & x);
   void erase(iterator & pos); 
   List<T> & operator=(const List<T> & l);
   List<T> & operator[] (unsigned int x);//OPERATOR []
   iterator reverse() const; //REVERSE 

protected:
   Link<T> * first_link;
   Link<T> * last_link;
   unsigned int my_size;
};

template <class T>
List<T>::List()
{
        first_link = 0;
        last_link = 0;
        my_size = 0;
}

template <class T>
List<T>::List(const List & l)
{
        first_link = 0;
        last_link = 0;
        my_size = 0;
        for (Link<T> * current = l.first_link; current != 0; current = current -> next_link)
                push_back(current -> value);
}

template <class T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::begin() const
{
    return iterator(first_link);
}

template <class T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::end() const
{
    return iterator (last_link);
}

//RBEGIN
template <class T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::rbegin() const
{
    return iterator (last_link);
}

//REND
template <class T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::rend() const
{
    return iterator(first_link);
}

template <class T> 
class Link 
{
private:
   Link(const T & x): value(x), next_link(0), prev_link(0) {}

   T value;     
   Link<T> * next_link;
   Link<T> * prev_link;

   friend class List<T>;
   friend class List_iterator<T>;
};

template <class T> class List_iterator
{
public:
   typedef List_iterator<T> iterator;

   List_iterator(Link<T> * source_link): current_link(source_link) { }
   List_iterator(): current_link(0) { }
   List_iterator(List_iterator<T> * source_iterator): current_link(source_iterator.current_link) { }

   T & operator*();
   iterator & operator=(const iterator & rhs);
   bool operator==(const iterator & rhs) const;
   bool operator!=(const iterator & rhs) const;
   iterator & operator++(); 
   iterator operator++(int);
   iterator & operator--(); 
   iterator operator--(int); 

protected:
   Link<T> * current_link;

   friend class List<T>;
};

template <class T>
T & List_iterator<T>::operator*()
{
        return current_link -> value;
}

template <class T>
List_iterator<T> List_iterator<T>::operator++(int)
{

}

template <class T>
List_iterator<T> & List_iterator<T>::operator--()
{
    current_link = current_link -> prev_link;
    return * this;
}

template <class T>
List_iterator<T> & List_iterator<T>::operator=(const iterator & rhs)
{
///???
}

template <class T>
List_iterator<T> List_iterator<T>::operator--(int)
{

}

template <class T>
List_iterator<T> & List_iterator<T>::operator++()
{
        current_link = current_link -> next_link;
        return *this;
}

template <class T>
void List<T>::push_back(const T & x)
{
    Link<T> * new_link = new Link<T> (x);
    if (first_link == 0)
    first_link = last_link = new_link;
    else
    {
    new_link->prev_link = last_link;
        last_link->next_link = new_link;    
        last_link = new_link;
    }
    my_size++;
}

template <class T>
List <T>::~List()
{
    Link <T> * first = first_link;
    while (first != 0)
    {
    Link <T> * next = first->next_link;
        delete first;
    first = next;
    }
}

template<class T>
bool List_iterator<T>::operator==(const iterator & rhs) const
{
    return ( this->current_link == rhs.current_link ); 
}

template <class T>
bool List_iterator<T>::operator!=(const iterator & rhs) const
{
    return !( *this == rhs );
}

//REVERSE ITERATOR
template <class T> class Reverse_iterator
{
public:
   typedef Reverse_iterator<T> riterator;

   Reverse_iterator(Link<T> * source_link): current_link(source_link) { }
   Reverse_iterator(): current_link(0) { }
   Reverse_iterator(List_iterator<T> * source_iterator): current_link(source_iterator.current_link) { }

   T & operator*();
   riterator & operator=(const riterator & rhs);
   bool operator==(const riterator & rhs) const;
   bool operator!=(const riterator & rhs) const;
   riterator & operator++(); 
   riterator operator++(int);
   riterator & operator--(); 
   riterator operator--(int); 

protected:
   Link<T> * current_link;

   friend class List<T>;
};

template <class T>
T & Reverse_iterator<T>::operator*()
{
        return current_link -> value;
}

template <class T>
Reverse_iterator<T> Reverse_iterator<T>::operator++(int)
{

}

template <class T>
Reverse_iterator<T> & Reverse_iterator<T>::operator--()
{
    current_link = current_link -> next_link;
    return * this;
}

template <class T>
Reverse_iterator<T> & Reverse_iterator<T>::operator=(const riterator & rhs)
{
//???
}

template <class T>
Reverse_iterator<T> Reverse_iterator<T>::operator--(int)
{

}

template<class T>
bool Reverse_iterator<T>::operator==(const riterator & rhs) const
{
    return ( this->current_link == rhs.current_link ); 
}

template <class T>
bool Reverse_iterator<T>::operator!=(const riterator & rhs) const
{
    return !( *this == rhs );
}


//REVERSE FUNCTION
template <class T>
List_iterator<T> List<T>::reverse() const
{
    iterator i, j;
    i = begin();
    j = end();
    for(; i != j; j++, j--)
    {
            T value = *j;
        *j = *i;
        *i = value;
    }
}

//OPERATOR []
template <class T>
List<T> & List<T>:: operator[] (unsigned int x)
{
    Link<T> * current = first_link;
    for(int i = 0; i != x && i < my_size; i++)
    current = current -> next_link;
    return current -> value;
    delete current;
}


//REVERSE ITERATOR OPERATOR ++()
template <class T>
Reverse_iterator<T> & Reverse_iterator<T>::operator++()
{
    current_link = current_link -> prev_link;
    return *this;
}

int main()
{
   List<int> l;

   l.push_back(44);
   l.push_back(33); 
   l.push_back(11); 
   l.push_back(22); 

   List<int> m(l);
   cout << "This is the original list" << endl;
   List<int>::iterator original(m.begin());
   while (original != m.end()) {
        cout << *original << endl;
        ++original;

   //cout << l[4]; //Not working

   //m.reverse();
   //cout << m;//Also Not working
   }
}
```

I am looking for help in:

- Writing my `operator=()` function, which is currently blank.
- Understanding why the last few lines in `main()` are not working (I know they are commented out) by going over my `operator[]` definition and my `reverse()` function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is too much code here. Please only post the sections you have questions about. Also, try to make your question more specific, perhaps consider splitting it up into several questions.

Comment: Basically, just wondering if someone could help with the [] operator on line 145 as my implementations have not worked thus far and wondering if someone could look over my reverse function, line 272, and tell me why it's returning an error in the terminal, I though that function was solid and am not sure what to change anymore. Sorry the question is so long.

Comment: see my answer below for help with operator[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding `List<T>::operator[]`**

I believe the main problem with your `operator[]` is that it's return type is `List<T>&` rather than `T&`. You want your `operator[]` to return a reference to a `T`, not a reference to an entire list. `Operator<<` has no idea how to deal with a `List<T>`, so it complains.

Additionally:

- That `delete` in `operator[]` is unreachable code. (As well as being wrong behaviour - why would you want to delete the link?)
- Your `operator[]` generates a couple of warnings because `i` is an `int` and `my_size` is `unsigned`. Easily corrected, see below.
- Consider what happens if, as @stefaanv has mentioned, someone asks for myList[4] when there are only 4 items in the list (collections index from zero, remember, so [4] is the fifth item. In your current logic, myList[3] would be returned instead - look carefully at the conditions in the for loop.

Here's what I think `operator[]` should look like:

```
template <class T>
T& List<T>:: operator[] (unsigned int x)
{
    if(x > (my_size - 1)
       || x < 0)
    {
        // throw a suitable exception - index out of bounds
    }

    Link<T> * current = first_link;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i != x && i < my_size; i++)
       current = current -> next_link;
    return current -> value;
}
```

...and see [here](http://ideone.com/Z698O) on IdeOne.

---

**Regarding `List<T>::reverse`**

First things first - to see the errors from `List_iterator<T> List<T>::reverse()`, you first need to fix your `main()`:

```
  //m.reverse();
  //cout << m;//Also Not working
```

Note that m is of type `List<int>`, so that `cout` line is trying to invoke the << opertaor on your `List<T>` class - but there isn't one, so you get errors. You could fix this either by:

1. Defining `operator<<` on your `List<T>` class
2. Replacing the `cout` line with a loop similar to the while loop in `main()`, which iterates through the list item by item.

Once you do one or the other of those, you'll see the real error messages coming from your reverse() function. For one thing, you've declared reverse as returning a `List_iterator<T>` - but it currently doesn't return anything!

Hope that helps! Good luck.

Comment: I don't have the ability to vote you up, but thank you very much, that helped tremendously.

Answer (score 1):

```
iterator begin() const;
iterator end() const;
iterator rbegin() const;//REVERSE BEGIN
iterator rend() const; //REVERSE END
```

I don't think you've to make these functions const.

It's better if you write two sets of these functions, one for non-const and other for const object.

```
//first set for non-const objects!
iterator begin();
iterator end();
iterator rbegin();
iterator rend();

//second set for const objects!
const_iterator begin() const;
const_iterator end() const;
const_iterator rbegin() const;
const_iterator rend() const;
```

This is the C++ Standard way of defining `begin` and `end` functions!

Answer (score 0):

errors in reverse:

```
j = end();
```

end() should points after the container, so j should have an extra decrement if the container is not empty.

```
for(; i != j; j++, j--)
```

1. j++ must be i++
2. for even numbers of elements, i will never be the same a j, use i > j

errors in main:

```
cout << l[4];
```

There are only 4 elements in your list and you're referencing the 5th, so this shouldn't work.

Comment: I changed the reverse function but I still have no clue as to how to properly display it in the terminal. Using `m.reverse(); cout << m;` doesn't work. As for the operator[] function, I forgot it should start with [0], so I changed it to [3] but I'm getting an error reading" `In member function 'List<T>& List<T>::operator[](unsigned int) [with T = int]':
323:   instantiated from here
294: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'List<int>&' from expression of type 'int'` which I am sure is because my operator= function, any ideas what that function should look like?